# Карета "скорой помощи"

Tags: фразеология, лексика

Недавно мне встретилось такое выражение. Раньше мне казалось, что оно давно устарело и употреблялось тогда, когда "скорые помощи" были на конной тяге, ну и в начале ХХ века еще по старинке. Употребительно ли это выражение сейчас и что из этого берется в кавычки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю, справедливо ли говорить "устарело", скорее просто вышло из активного употребления, оставаясь в пассивном запасе. Устаревающим же следует признавать слово, выходящее и из пассивного запаса, т.е. становящееся необычным и непонятным для большинства носителей языка. До этого пока далеко.

Кавычек не требуется. Заглавных букв, кстати, тоже.

Да, забыл. Во второй половине XX века сочетание было еще вполне употребительно. Личные воспоминания начала 60-х. Правда это слыхивано от бабушек-дедушек.

Answer (score 6):

Выражение *карета скорой помощи* сейчас вполне употребительно, слышу его часто. Никаких кавычек не нужно.